# Protractor dealing with promises and arrays in flow control

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm working on some Jasmine end-to-end testing, using Protractor test runner. The application I am testing is a simple webpage. I already have a test scenario that works fine.

Now I'd like to improve my code so that I can use the same script to run the testing scenario twice.

- The first time: the test would be performed on the English version of the page
- The second time: on a translated version of the same page.

Here is my code:

```
var RandomSentenceInThePage = ["Sentence in English", "Phrase en Francais"];
var i;
var signInButton;
var TranslationButton;
var RandomSentenceInThePageBis;
i = 0;
//Runs the testing scenario twice
while (i < 2) {
  describe('TC1 - The registration Page', function() {
    //the translation is done on the second iteration
    if (i != 0) {
      beforeEach(function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('https://Mywebsite.url.us/');
        //we get the translation button then click on it
        TranslationButton = element(by.css('.TranslationButtonClass'));
        TranslationButton.click();
      });
    }
    //On the first iteration, we run the test on the not translated page…
    Else {
      beforeEach(function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; //Necessary for the browser.get() method to work inside the it statements.
        browser.get('https://Mywebsite.url.us/');
      });
    }

    it('should display the log in page', function() {
      //Accessing the browser is done in the before each section
      signInButton = element(by.css('.SignInButtonClass'));
      signInButton.click();

      RandomSentenceInThePageBis = element(by.css('.mt-4.text-center.signin-header')).getText();
      /*******************[HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS]*******************/
      expect(RandomSentenceInThePageBis.getText()).toEqual(RandomSentenceInThePage[i]);
    });
    /*******************************************************************/
  });
}
```

I have highlighted the problematic section. The code keeps running even before the comparison between RandomSentenceInThePage[i] and RandomSentenceInThePageBis are compared. And when they are finally compared, the loop is already done.

According to what I have seen on the other related topics, because of the use of expect statements and getText() methods, I am dealing with promises and I have to wait for them to be resolved. After trying for the whole day, I think I could use a hint on how to deal with this promise resolution. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `while` loop to `for` loop and declare the variable: `i` by `let`, rather than `var`

`let` can declare variable at code block scope like `for`, `if` block etc. But `var` can't.

Because protractor api execute async, thus when the `expect()...` execute for the second time. the value of `i` has become `2`, not `1`

```
for(let i=0;i<2;i++) {

  describe('TC1 - The registration Page', function() {
     ....
  })
}
```